# jQuery Checkbox Filtering with .detach() + .appendTo()

Tags: jquery, html

I am probably missing something very simple, but here is the situation:

I have a row of checkboxes and a grid of list-items. I want the checkboxes to be toggling the visibility of the list items depending on what is checked (just standard filtering).

I have determined that I have to use the jQuery .detach() & .appendTo() functions, as this will keep all of my :nth-child attributes in tact when list-items are disappearing/reappearing.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="filter">
  <input type="checkbox" id="print" rel="print">Print</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="web" rel="web">Web</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="identity" rel="identity">Identity</label>
</div>
```

And then I have a ton of LI's with various tag names in the class fields --

```
<ul>
  <li class="print">
    // stuff
  </li>
  .
  .
  .
</ul>
```

And now for my jQuery (which is working for the first time you click a filter checkbox, but then it doesn't do anything after that...)

```
$('#filter').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {  
   var $lis = $('#grid-wrap > li').detach();        

   //For each one checked
   $('input:checked').each(function() {
     $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).appendTo('#grid-wrap');
    });  
});
```

Any help would be super appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Im not exactly sure what this would look like, however I would probably use CSS to hide things, instead of `detach`. (`visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;`)

Comment: @teak -- I would use CSS, except when you simply do 'display:none' on an element, the element is still in the DOM, meaning the nth-child selectors are still calculating the hidden divs, messing up the layout!

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted to preserve `nth-child`. Just ignore that comment then. Maybe make a JSFiddle, so we can see what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then you are trying to show/hide `li`'s based on selection. Let me kow if I this is not what you want,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/W2LRg/4/)

```
var $lis;

$('#filter').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {

    if (!$lis) $lis = $('#grid-wrap > li').detach();
    $('#grid-wrap').empty();

    if ($('input:checked').length == 0) {
        $lis.appendTo('#grid-wrap');
        $lis = null;
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox').each(function(i, chk) {
            if (chk.checked) {
                $lis.filter('.' + $(chk).attr('rel')).appendTo('#grid-wrap');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to remove the li when the checkbox is unchecked? This solution is so close! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @briankulp Try the updated DEMO and let me know if it is what you want

Comment: Ehh, when you uncheck a box, it should hide that corresponding li element. I can't wrap my head around this!

Comment: @briankulp Do you want to hide or detach? hiding is totally different, if hide then we should not use detach. Let me know

Comment: Well, sort of both! X-) I just need to detach the elements so that the remaining visible list-items have the proper layout with the nth-child selectors that I have on there. However, when you uncheck a box, the corresponding elements shouldn't be visible.

Comment: @briankulp It is confusing.. Do you have 2 `ul li` and you are moving elements from one to another based on selection. Can you give an example of what you want or set a http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: The fiddle works correctly the first time you click a checkbox 'IE - Print', the other two categories go away, leaving just Print LI's... however, once you uncheck that, instead of hiding the print li's, nothing happens.

Comment: @briankulp mm.. still confusing.. if the checkboxes are filter, then when you uncheck `Print` shouldn't it show all `li`s again?

Comment: Yeah, your right. It should show all LI's that are currently checked. If none of the checkboxes are checked, no LI's would be seen. Making more sense now? :)

Comment: @briankulp Try >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/W2LRg/2/ << and let me know if this is what you wanted..

Comment: Yes! This is the interaction that I was going for! The only issue is that since the elements are still in the DOM, so the nth-child properties are messing up the layout! (it's still calculating the li's that aren't being displayed)

Comment: Here is how the grid/layout should look -- http://cl.ly/GXic, and here is how it looks when you only use .show() and .hide() on the li's -- http://cl.ly/GXAd. I was trying to use .detach() and .appendTo(), since that will fix the problem, but can't figure out how to implement it into the solution you gave me! Any ideas? BTW, thank you so much for your help so far, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @briankulp Check this >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/W2LRg/4/ << This is similar to what i had earlier

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I really, really appreciate the help. Maybe you could post that last fiddle in your original answer as an edit? Thanks a lot!